# I can not turn off testng internal logging in console

Tags: java, logging, testng, logback, slf4j

output

```
    14:42:32.418 [main] DEBUG org.testng.internal.Graph - [Graph] ================ SORTING
    14:42:32.476 [main] DEBUG org.testng.internal.Graph - [Graph] =============== DONE SORTING
    14:42:32.476 [main] DEBUG org.testng.internal.Graph - [Graph] ====== SORTED NODES
    14:42:32.476 [main] DEBUG org.testng.internal.Graph - [Graph] ====== END SORTED NODES
    14:42:32.476 [main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.sortMethods() took 61 ms.
    14:42:32.478 [main] INFO org.testng.internal.Utils - [Utils] MethodGroupsHelper.collectMethodsByGroup() took 0 ms.
    14:42:32.479 [main] DEBUG org.testng.internal.Graph - [Graph] ADDING NODE TestBase.appiumTearDown()[pri:0, instance:null] 1618865525
    14:42:32.479 [main] DEBUG org.testng.internal.Graph - [Graph] ================ SORTING
    14:42:32.479 [main] DEBUG org.testng.internal.Graph - [Graph] =============== DONE SORTING
    14:42:32.479 [main] DEBUG org.testng.internal.Graph - [Graph] ====== SORTED NODES
    14:42:32.479 [main] DEBUG org.testng.internal.Graph - [Graph] ====== END SORTED NODES
```

My Logger implementation

```
<configuration>
<appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
</root>
```

My Logger Class

```
public class LogManager extends TestBase {
protected static ThreadLocal<StringBuilder> log = ThreadLocal.withInitial(StringBuilder::new);

public static void log(String msg) {
    log.get().append(msg).append("\n");
}

@BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
public void setUp() {
    TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
    testNG.setVerbose(2);
    Logger bonigarcia = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("io.github.bonigarcia");
    Logger testng = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.testng");
    Logger apache = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.apache");
    Logger slack = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.slack.api");
    Logger gitHub = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("org.kohsuke");

    bonigarcia.setLevel(Level.WARN);
    testng.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
    apache.setLevel(Level.WARN);
    slack.setLevel(Level.WARN);
    gitHub.setLevel(Level.WARN);
    log.remove();
}
```

}

I am starting my test suit with mvn command and I can not prevent logging from testng because it runs before my codes. I found that in the testng documentation but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

> Starting from TestNG version 7.5 TestNG makes use of the logging facade provided by Slf4j.
> TestNG by default does not bring in any explicit Slf4j facade implementation.
> To control the logs being output by TestNG internals, please add a dependency on any suitable Slf4j implementation (Native Or Wrapped implementation) from here

My logback.xml path => src/test/resources/logback.xml

Pom testng dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven plugins

```
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>*.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>10</source>
            <target>10</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>integration-test</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>
                        ${project.build.directory}/libs
                    </outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test-jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
        <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>
        <configuration>
            <repository>athena</repository>
            <tag>test</tag>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
        <configuration>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            <parallel>classes</parallel>
            <threadCount>${threadCount}</threadCount>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
                <propertyName>${env}</propertyName>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to do the following for getting this to work

Add the below to your `logback.xml`

```xml
<logger name="org.testng" level="debug">
  <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
</logger>
```

The logger is initialised much before the `@BeforeSuite` is called which perhaps is why the logging levels that you are attempting to set is NOT getting honoured.

But if you set the log levels from your log configuration file (`logback.xml` in this case) you should be fine!

Comment: I tried that one but still, logs are keep coming

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add information in terms of where the file was added (`src/main/resources` (or) `src/test/resources` ?) and also add details on TestNG dependency scope ?

Comment: You would need to remove `<includes><include>*.properties</include></includes>` from your pom file, because you are causing the `logback.xml` file to be excluded from being made available in the CLASSPATH. Please remove that

Comment: @Efe - In that case, I would suggest that you edit your question and add a link to a sample project which can be used to reproduce the problem (maybe you can create a sample project and upload it to github). That way it would be a lot easier to find out what is missing here.

Comment: adding include *.xml simply solved the problem, I will update the problem accordingly

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Krishnan
I updated the pom and logback accordingly and problem solved

pom.xml

```
<testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>*.properties</include>
                <include>*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
```

logback.xml

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </root>
    <logger name="org.testng" level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```